# Display/Hide divs on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

*jquery* noob here.

I've got these divs on my main page as a frame:

```
#top, #bottom, #left, #right {
    background: #000000;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999999;
}
#left, #right {
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 0.9em;
}
#left { left: 0; }
#right { right: 0; }    
#top, #bottom {
    left: 0; right: 0;
    height: 0.9em;
}
#top { top: 0; }
#bottom { bottom: 0; }
```

So far, this works perfectly.

Also, I am displaying my portfolio, in a regular manner, throught the [Swipebox](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/) plugin. Inside the gallery, after clicking one of my thumbnails, I want to add this very frame but in white color, like this:

```
#top, #bottom, #left, #right {
    background: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999999;
}
#left, #right {
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 0.9em;
}
#left { left: 0; }
#right { right: 0; }
#top, #bottom {
    left: 0; right: 0;
    height: 0.9em;
}
#top { top: 0; }
#bottom { bottom: 0; }
```

The problem comes with the *z-index* bit though; If I put a bigger *z-index* on the black frame, the white one will not be displayed, and the other way round.

I was wondering how to, by default, display the black one (as it's the "main" one, being in the main page) and, when clicking the thumbnail to have access to the gallery, and only then, display the white frame over the black one.

Any thoughts? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I can't tell what you mean from just css that you provided. Please provide any additional html/js code that you are using, and a working jsfiddle would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Hi, you are right. Take a look to this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ormn9ajs/

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is, after clickin the <a>, change the color of the frame from black to white.

Comment: Please include all code directly in your question.  External resources, such as the jsFiddle that you provided, and comments are to be used for supplementary purposes.  All information necessary to understand and be able to answer the question needs to be included in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to add additional duplicate divs with a different background color. Instead just change the color of the frame when you click on the link.

Assuming I understand you correctly, this https://jsfiddle.net/2wqffhnj/3/ is what you are trying to accomplish, right?

I simply added a class

```
.frame-color {
    background: #000000;
}
```

and swap that color when you click the link

```
$("#frame-swap").click(function() {
    if ($(".frame-color").css("background-color") == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
    $(".frame-color").css({"background":"#ffffff"});
  }
  else {
    $(".frame-color").css({"background-color":"#000000"});
  }
});
```

Comment: This answer is simply beautiful, exactly providing what I was looking for. Thanks heaps, Jd Francis!

Comment: Just to extend the question, sorry to bother again: when clicking on the ID named #frame-swap, apart from changing the frame color, I open the Swipebox jquery lightbox. How could we do for, when closing that lightbox, the frame go back to normal (black) instead of remaining white as it is now?

Comment: As option: http://jsfiddle.net/lega911/txdbsmdh/

Answer (score 0):

The z-index is just a number that specifies the stack order, so you want to swap the white frame for the black frame on click so I would take a look at this answer.
[jQuery swap z-index on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043849/jquery-swap-z-index-on-hover)